# Regular expression to find all function calls with parameters in VS2010

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

Say I have a function called myFunc(). It can take parameters. I want to find all instances of myFunc() which HAS parameters passed in. What regular expression should I use? I'm using Ctrl+Shift+F in VS2010 and have Use Regular Expressions option selected.

So for example, I want to see

myFunc( varA )

myFunc( varB, varC)

and not

myFunc()

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, I got down voted hard for this. LOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple but should do what you are looking for:

```
myFunc\([^)]+\)
```

basically looking for:
 - `myFunc\(` = `myFunc(`
 - `[^)]+` = one or more of something besides `)`
 - `\)` = followed by a `)`

visually:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown of the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
myFunc\(\s*\S.*\)
```

The \s* checks for zero or more spaces before. \S makes sure at least one non-space is found, and .* tales everything that might also be there.

note that the parantheses is also escaped