# Finding functions with default value in javascript

Tags: regex, function, sublimetext3, default-value

I am having error when uploading my website on heroku as having default values in function.
Until now I have used default value lots of times and they are in 50000 column javascript file and I cant really find all of them.
So I tried to find all functions with default values in sublime using regex.
I tried this regular expression.

```
function.*\(.*\=.*\)
```

But it's finding this kind of string(which is not default value function).

```
Function(e)) return Q.grep(t, function(t, i) { return !!e.call(t, i, t) !== n })
```

Sample function to be searched

```
var abc = function(x , y = 1)
function abc(x , y = 1)
```

Please help, I am new to regular expression and it's really difficult to find answer.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Maybe it's easier to fix that rather than your code.

Comment: I am getting `ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token operator «=», expected punc «,»` and I found answer that uglify doesn't support default value in functions so I am going to change all functions with default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex `function[a-zA-Z ]*\([a-zA-Z \,]+[a-zA-Z ]*[=]`. It will match the functions with default parameters regardless of number of parameters. I hope this helped.

Comment: Would you like to make snippet for more visualization.

Comment: Try this `function*\([a-zA-Z \,]+[a-zA-Z ]*[=]` . This should work. I will also edit my old answer

Comment: Your answer is finding similar ones but it's not finding `function abc(d, e, f, g, h, i = 30)` function.

Comment: Try now `function[a-zA-Z ]*\([a-zA-Z \,]+[a-zA-Z ]*[=]` . This will do it. I also edited my answer. If it works please appreciate the efforts and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `function[\s\w]*\([\w\s\d,]*[\w\s]+=[\w\d\s'",]*\)`. Default value may be string, and also function may have name:
`var abc = function some_name (x , y = 1, z = "string", z_z) { var = 1`

Comment: It is finding `function C(t, e) { return { get: function() { return t() ? void delete this.get : (this.get = e)`

Comment: I've updated the answer. Try the new version, please.

Comment: Not finding all

Answer (score 0):

```
function\([^)]+\)
```

and take refernce from this:

[Regular expression to find all function calls with parameters in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679630/regular-expression-to-find-all-function-calls-with-parameters-in-vs2010)

Comment: It's not finding functions with default value.